# How to route all data traffic through a proxy server?

Tags: internet, networking

I'd like to route ***all*** my network traffic over a proxy server to allow me to sniff and measure the traffic. What are my options for doing that?

Even if it isn't nativly supported on the device / OS, is there a work around? For example on Android there is an App that adds that functionality on an unlocked device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure a proxy when connected to a Wi-Fi network; first go to Settings; Then to WiFi. Turn WiFi on if it isn't already, and allow it to connect. Tap on the network to bring up the details, you'll see a sliderr for proxy, and you can turn it on, and configure the server, port; and optionally any authentication.

Comment: So no proxy on 3G?

Comment: When connected to a WiFi network, all HTTP traffic will go via the WiFi network, and use the associated settings. When connected via a cellular connection (be it GPRS, 3G, HSCSD, etc.) it will use the provider's network (who may, in turn, provide a proxy of their own). For the purposes of sniffing, the WiFi option should suffice.